# Share webcam on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, webcam, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intranet Video-streaming](https://superuser.com/questions/26401/intranet-video-streaming)

There are two connected PCs via Ethernet. One has a USB web-camera. How can I watch the camera at one machine (it does not have the camera) not notably for other?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/26401/intranet-video-streaming. Please see here for answers to your question.

Answer (score 0):

[Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/) is a free open source program that should allow you to do this.